# What's the difference in this code (JS)?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm wondering what's the difference between this code:

```
var c = [{"test": 1}];
```

and this code

```
var c = {"test": 1};
```

Firebug says both of them are objects but if you do console.log(c.test) with the first example it'll return "undefined". So I'm kind of wondering what's that all about and how should the first example be accessed?

Comment: *"Firebug says both of them are objects..."* They **are** both objects. As Darin said, the first is an array (which is an object) containing one element, which is an object with the property `test`. The second is just an object (with the property `test`).

Comment: If you had typed in Firebug 'console.dir(c);' instead, you would have seen the difference immediately. :)

Comment: In JavaScript, almost everything is an object. Unlike "real" programming language only few of them have explicit type (e.g. Number, String) and most are treated as "general" objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is an array containing one element which is the `{"test": 1}` object while the second is the `{"test": 1}` object itself.

So with the first you could `c[0].test` while with the second you could `c.test`.

Answer (score 1):

The first c is an Array containing an Object, the second an Object.

In JavaScript everything is an Object, so that's why Firebug says they are both objects. To get the test property from the first c, you have to reference the first element of the Array (being the actual Object), so `c[0].test` would return 1. If you need to know if c is (instance of) an Array, try typing `c instanceof Array` in the Firebug console and run it (returns `true`). To verify that an Array is also an Object do the same for `c instanceof Object` (returns `true`).